# Search for unknown item in list and append to variable

Tags: python, string, list

I need to gather a list of components from a file. The components are always in the same format which is '(Space)(Space)(Component)(Space)'

Here is how the file is formatted;

```
  C500          1u    10    10 f PN"00210856" "CAP 1uF 10% 0805";
  C501          1n    10    10 f PN"00072210" "CAP 1nF 10% 0402";
  C502         22n    10    10 f PN"00196403" "CAP 22nF 10% 0603";
  C503      9.999p    10    10 f PN"C_NF" "NO FIT CAPACITOR";
  C504      9.999p    10    10 f PN"C_NF" "NO FIT CAPACITOR";
  C505      9.999p    10    10 f PN"C_NF" "NO FIT CAPACITOR";
```

I have a list which contains this data I only need the component ie C500,C501 etc. Some components are more that 4 characters long.

I want the output to be Components = 'C500','C501','C502'...

Comment: just filter the 1st column

Comment: Are you reading this data in from a text file

Comment: It is a list of strings. So the entire sample is a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the file, and for each line split it on whitespace and take the first item.

```py
components = []
with open(components.txt) as file:
    for line in file:
        component = line.split()[0]
        components.append(component)
```

In your post you say it's a file but in your comments you say it's a list of strings. Here's the list version:

```py
components = []
for line in your_component_data:
    component = line.split()[0]
    components.append(component)
```

Comment: With the argument to `split()`, won't it produce extraneous empty items where there are multiple spaces?

Comment: It will. However, unless there are spaces before the component name it won't matter. If there are, use ```strip()``` first.

Comment: You might want to add that to your answer, as the question explicitly mentions there are two spaces before the item he's looking for. A better solution would probably be to simply omit the argument to `split()`.

Comment: Is this a file, a string, or a list of strings? You're jumping around between the 3 of those and they're very much not interchangeable. It's also possible you've used ```split('')``` instead of ```split(' ')```

Comment: Sorry, it was my fault. I had used the entire string instead of using the list of strings. The data came from a file which I turned into a list of strings.

Answer (score 0):

you said its a list of strings and the entire sample is a string to that seems a bit of a contradiction. Below assumes you have it all as a string but can easily be adapted for a list of strings.

```
data = """  C500          1u    10    10 f PN"00210856" "CAP 1uF 10% 0805";
  C501          1n    10    10 f PN"00072210" "CAP 1nF 10% 0402";
  C502         22n    10    10 f PN"00196403" "CAP 22nF 10% 0603";
  C503      9.999p    10    10 f PN"C_NF" "NO FIT CAPACITOR";
  C504      9.999p    10    10 f PN"C_NF" "NO FIT CAPACITOR";
  C505      9.999p    10    10 f PN"C_NF" "NO FIT CAPACITOR";"""

components = ["'"+line.split()[0]+"'" for line in data.splitlines()]
print("components =", ",".join(components))
```

OUTPUT

```
components = 'C500','C501','C502','C503','C504','C505'
```

Further example incase you have a list of strings.

```
data = ['C500          1u    10    10 f PN"00210856" "CAP 1uF 10% 0805";',
        'C501          1n    10    10 f PN"00072210" "CAP 1nF 10% 0402";',
        'C502         22n    10    10 f PN"00196403" "CAP 22nF 10% 0603";',
        'C503      9.999p    10    10 f PN"C_NF" "NO FIT CAPACITOR";',
        'C504      9.999p    10    10 f PN"C_NF" "NO FIT CAPACITOR";',
        'C505      9.999p    10    10 f PN"C_NF" "NO FIT CAPACITOR";'
        ]

components = ["'"+line.split()[0]+"'" for line in data]
print("components =", ",".join(components))
```